# Liquibase - mvn generateChangeLog - diffExcludeObjects doesn't work with columns

Tags: maven, liquibase

i migrated from Flyway to Liquibase and now i want to use the following command to export our data.
The diffExcludeObjects functionality works great with tables. In my example, it doesn't export the tables CONTENT_IMAGE and schema_version.

**It should work with columns, too (http://www.liquibase.org/2015/01/liquibase-3-3-2-released.html), but it doesn't.** My export csv contains the column MAIL_ADDRESS. I haven't found a way to exclude specific columns from an export. [My table with the column looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEo82.png)

Also the mvn command doc (https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_generateChangeLog.html) sais, that it should work.

**Command**

```
mvn org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:generateChangeLog \
-Dliquibase.propertyFile="src/main/resources/db/liquibase/connection-to-database.properties" \
-Dliquibase.dataDir="src/main/resources/db/liquibase/export" \
-Dliquibase.diffTypes="data" \
-Dliquibase.diffExcludeObjects="table:CONTENT_IMAGE, column:MAIL_ADDRESS, table:schema_version" \
-Dliquibase.promptOnNonLocalDatabase="false"
```

Do i understand this feature wrong? Do i use it wrong? Please, i need help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `-Dliquibase.diffExcludeObjects="table:CONTENT_IMAGE, column:MAIL_ADDRESS"`? Without `table:schema_version`.

Comment: I tried, but the column is still available at the csv-files.